# Issue with Integration tests in maven

Tags: java, maven, kotlin

I have my integration tests for a kotlin app in a separate folder like,

```
src ->
     it -> kotlin
       -> resources
    main -> kotlin
         ->resources
    test -> kotlin
         -> resource
```

I have added the below configurations to my pom.xml for running the integration tests

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.xxx.api</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-sort</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-sort</name>

  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <kotlin.version>1.3.31</kotlin.version>


    <opentracing-brave.version>0.34.2</opentracing-brave.version>
    <reactor.version>3.3.1.RELEASE</reactor.version>

    <!-- testing libraries versions-->
    <mockk.version>1.9</mockk.version>
    <kotlin.junit.version>1.3.41</kotlin.junit.version>
    <wiremock.version>2.24.1</wiremock.version>
    <jacoco.version>0.8.4</jacoco.version>
    <spring-cloud-sleuth.version>2.1.2.RELEASE</spring-cloud-sleuth.version>
    <brave.version>5.6.11</brave.version>
  </properties>


 <build>
    <finalName>my-sort</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
    <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sourceDirs>
                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
              </sourceDirs>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>test-compile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sourceDirs>
                <source>src/test/kotlin</source>
                <source>src/it/kotlin</source>
              </sourceDirs>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <args>
            <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
          </args>
          <compilerPlugins>
            <plugin>spring</plugin>
          </compilerPlugins>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>/com/xxx/api/**/*</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-report</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-check</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <rule>
                  <element>BUNDLE</element>
                  <limits>
                    <limit>
                      <counter>COMPLEXITY</counter>
                      <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                      <!-- change this to the required minimum code coverage -->
                      <minimum>0.0</minimum>
                    </limit>
                  </limits>
                </rule>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
          <id>add-integration-test-resources</id>
          <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <resources>
              <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/it/resources</directory>
              </resource>
            </resources>
          </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*IT.kt</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>failsafe-integration-tests</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

All the classes for integration tests cases are ending with IT.kt, When ever I ran mvn verify only unit test cases are ran and fail safe report always show

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<failsafe-summary result="254" timeout="false">
  <completed>0</completed>
  <errors>0</errors>
  <failures>0</failures>
  <skipped>0</skipped>
  <failureMessage/>
</failsafe-summary>
```

Comment: nope, I just want to ran integration tests when any profile run's mvn verify

Comment: I tried adding 

<configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>com.xxx.api.it</include>
          </includes>
it's not working

Comment: tried those already, not working.

Comment: tried it, not working.

Comment: Note that you need to use the `java`-extension in the `include` of `failsafe`, i.e. `**/*IT.java`... otherwise they will not be picked up... under the hood that `java` is replaced by `class`... that's why your tests will be picked up, if you have `*IT.kt`-files in place... but that's also the reason why `**/*IT.kt` doesn't pick them up...

Comment: tried changing it to IT.java and ran mvn integration-tests and mvn verify. 
still not working.

Comment: hmmm... that works for me... so it runs no test? neither unit, nor integration test?

Comment: it always ran UT

Comment: so now you have `<include>**/*IT.java</include>` in `failsafe` and `*IT.kt`-classes there (where the `class` within also ends in `IT`, right?)... just asking enough question to be sure that we talk about the same thing... sorry if that annoys you ;-)

Comment: Yes, the classes are ending with IT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206348/discussion-between-robin-and-roland).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`failsafe` (and also `surefire`) internally replace `java`-occurrences in the `include`-matcher to `class`. That means you can't use `**/*IT.kt` there, but need to use `**/*IT.java` instead (or `**/*Test.java` in case of `surefire`). Doesn't matter if you really have java-files there.

Another guess is, that you forgot telling the kotlin compiler that it should compile those files under `src/it/kotlin` too, i.e.:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>test-compile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirs>
                    <source>src/test/kotlin</source>
                    <source>src/it/kotlin</source>
                </sourceDirs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

A bit related: [documentation regarding adding Java and Kotlin source folders](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html#compiling-kotlin-and-java-sources). In your case it is 2 Kotlin source folders instead of Java and Kotlin folder (that's also the reason why you do not need to overwrite the `maven-compiler-plugin`-configuration).

This is the only thing I see which might be missing. The rest should be ok.

Comment: well... these are test classes, right? it's just another kind of test... unit vs integration test...

Comment: finally fixed the issue  with your changes and upgrading maven fail safe version from 2.18.1 to 2.22.1, thank you

Comment: I tested with `2.18.1`, so the version shouldn't be a problem... but glad it worked... we may need to cleanup the comments a bit...

Comment: but if I use 2.18.1 and then try it it's not working strange actully.
you meant delete the previous comments ?

Comment: ... I used a stripped-down `pom.xml` (no spring, no jacoco, etc.)... maybe another plugin interferes with it? So good to know that version upgrade is required as well for you...